# Bring amadeus form to website

Tags: javascript, php, forms, amadeus

I've tried several things, but none of them work...

https://www.epower.amadeus.com/sadeem/

i need to bring this form in my website & can redsign it ... only form ,

when user write query then go to direct to result page in amadeus website

i tried iframe , .load() but dosen't work .

in this test i tried to get only flight section

```
<iframe src="https://www.epower.amadeus.com/sadeem/ #Obj_Flight"  width="1000" height="500"></iframe>
```

Comment: You have a space in front of the # in your url. Works just fine. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yambypwx/).

Comment: i want to bring only flight form & then bring hotel form and can redesign it like these examples :
http://www.omeir.com/
http://www.aerogaga.com/

Comment: Sorry, just saw that. If you are not on the same domain, this will not work do to **same origin policy**

Comment: @DavidDomain thank you , its on different domain.

Answer (score 0):

I am work e-power development team as technical Expert. Your portal is seems not active. You can't design for now.

You can use below parameters for goto result page directly with a start new search. Date format can be `different` on your site `settings`.

```
#AdtCount=1&From=FRA&To=AMS&DepartureDate=21.03.2016&ReturnDate=28.03.2016&Method=Search
```

Comment: Hello. I can't find url switches documentation for Amadeus epower anywhere, could you help me find one?